# Combining multiple Bool return values without shortcircuiting

Tags: objective-c, swift, bitwise-and

Swift 2 has restrictions on using bitwise operators for `Bool` values. This is agreeable. In ObjC it was very useful to use it when you need to execute each operand. For example:

```
a.isFoo() & b.isFoo() & c.isFoo()
```

In this case, using the bitwise **&** will execute each method.

If I use the logical operator **&&**, it will execute the first one and if it is false, the expression will return false without executing the other two operands.

I want to find the same elegant way that **&** works, with `Bool` in Swift. Is it possible?

Comment: I believe there is no such operator (logical AND that doesn't short-circuit) but you can create such an operator yourself. Or just save the results into variables first and then do `&&`.

Comment: What you were doing in Objective-C was not "elegant". It was skanky and you shouldn't have been doing it. If you want to call three methods, just call those three methods! But forming a boolean expression, you should use the _logical_ operators, not the _bitwise_ operators.

Comment: I don't agree with you @matt . It looks elegant and short. May be it depends  on coding culture. People who coded in c/c++ before like such style.

Comment: It is very implementation dependent in that it depends on very precise values being returned to get the correct result.  Given that anything non-zero is true, that means if they returned 1, 2, and 4, the result would be false using your code.  Implementation dependent results qualifies as skanky in my book.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you were doing in Objective-C was not "elegant". It was skanky and you shouldn't have been doing it. If you want to call three methods, just call those three methods! But forming a boolean expression, you should use the logical operators, not the bitwise operators. So, for example:

```
let (ok1, ok2, ok3) = (a.isBool(), b.isBool(), c.isBool())
let ok = ok1 && ok2 && ok3
```

Comment: In Objective-C it wasn't just skanky but broken. Prior to the 64-bit runtime `BOOL` was just a `typedef` for `char` and therefore has 255 different versions of `YES`. So `YES & YES & YES` can evaluate to `NO`, whereas `YES && YES && YES` cannot. Quickest source I could find: https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/bools-sharp-corners/

Comment: @Tommy Yes, that's what I meant. Perhaps I shouldn't scold the OP, because I've actually made this mistake _as a mistake_, and was caught with my pants down when my code worked until suddenly it didn't. Yet another reason why I ran screaming towards Swift the moment it appeared.

Comment: Cool. I thought maybe you were just focussing on the getters-should-not-have-side-effects rule, which I would consider would also outlaw things like `a.isBoolGivenThat(thisIs: this, thatIs: that)` having side effects, assuming the original author has simplified for the purposes of asking. Yuck.

Comment: for my case I pretty sure that isFoo() returns BOOL, not int or other type. I agree with @Tommy that YES can be presented as 1..255 (256 will be again NO and so on) in case of use non-BOOL.

Comment: In the 32-bit runtime — i.e. on all devices prior to the iPhone 5s — `BOOL` exactly is `char`.

Answer (score 2):

There is no such special operator but I would probably do it in this way:

```
if ![a.isBool(), b.isBool(), c.isBool()].contains(false) {
```

or just

```
let aCondition = a.isBool()
let bCondition = b.isBool()
let cCondition = c.isBool()

if aCondition && bCondition && cCondition {
```

but you can can also define your own operator to that.

Answer (score 2):

You could mimic the same behaviour using a `reduce` operation on an array of your method calls, e.g.

```
/* example setup */
struct Foo {
    let bar: Bool
    init(_ bar: Bool) { self.bar = bar }

    func isTrue() -> Bool { print("\(bar) foo!"); return bar }
}

let a = Foo(false)
let b = Foo(false)
let c = Foo(true)

/* naturally all three method calls will execute to construct the boolean
   array, whereafter reduce will evaluate the combined conditional statement */ 
if [a.isTrue(), b.isTrue(), c.isTrue()].reduce(true, combine: { $0 && $1 }) {
    print("Reached this ...")
} /* false foo!
     false foo!
     true foo! */

let d = Foo(true)
let e = Foo(true)
let f = Foo(true)

if [d.isTrue(), e.isTrue(), f.isTrue()].reduce(true, combine: { $0 && $1 }) {
    print("Reached this ...")
} /* true foo!
     true foo!
     true foo!
     Reached this ... */
```

or e.g. supplying your methods as variadic arguments to a function doing the method execution and combined conditional

```
func foo(calls: (() -> Bool)...) -> Bool {
    return calls.map{ $0() }.reduce(true, combine: { $0 && $1})
}

let a = Foo(false)
let b = Foo(false)
let c = Foo(true)

if foo(a.isTrue, b.isTrue, c.isTrue) {
    print("Reached this ...")
} /* false foo!
     false foo!
     true foo! */

let d = Foo(true)
let e = Foo(true)
let f = Foo(true)

if foo(d.isTrue, e.isTrue, f.isTrue) {
    print("Reached this ...")
} /* true foo!
     true foo!
     true foo!
     Reached this ... */
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let values = [a.isFoo(), b.isFoo(), c.isFoo()]
let result = values.allSatisfy { $0 }
```